# Parsing XML with Python from URL using minidom

Tags: python, xml, parsing, minidom

I have a problem during parsing the following xml from a url.

sample XML in my url path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Documents>
    <class>
        <mid name="yyyyyyyyyyyyy"></mid>
        <person name="yyyyyyyyyy"></person>
        <url name="yyyyyyyyy"></url>
    </class>
    <class>
        <mid name="xxxxx"></mid>
        <person name="xxxxxxxxxx"></person>
        <url name="xxxxxxxxxxx"></url>
    </class>
</Documents>
```

Below is my python code;

```python
def staff_list(request):

    url = http://path.to.url/
    dom = minidom.parse(urlopen(url))
    person = dom.getElementsByTagName('person')
    for i in person:
        print i.attributes['name'].value
```

within forloop I want to print the person and url tag values in xml that belongs  to same parent class.

I tried the **following** method with iteration but get the **"too many values to unpack"** ERROR

```python
def staff_list(request):

    url = http://path.to.url/
    dom = minidom.parse(urlopen(url))
    person = dom.getElementsByTagName('person')
    mid = dom.getElementsByTagName('mid')
    url = dom.getElementsByTagName('url')
    for i,j,k in person,mid,url:
        print i.attributes['name'].value,j.attributes['name'].value,k.attributes['name'].value
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `zip()` to combine the elements, I think:

```
for i,j,k in zip(person, mid, url):
```

Do yourself a big favour though and use the [ElementTree API](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) instead; that API is far pythononic and easier to use than the XML DOM API.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with `minidom` you can change your loop to:

```
for cls in dom.getElementsByTagName('class'):
    person = cls.getElementsByTagName('person')[0]
    mid = cls.getElementsByTagName('mid')[0]
    url = cls.getElementsByTagName('url')[0]

    print person.attributes['name'].value
    print mid.attributes['name'].value
    print url.attributes['name'].value
```

As @Martijn Pieters said, have a look at ElementTree as an alternative API. For example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
documents = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)
for cls in documents.iter('class'):
    person = cls.find('person')
    mid = cls.find('mid')
    url = cls.find('url')

    print person.get('name'), mid.get('name'), url.get('name')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use xpath and lxml.html:
A minimalist approach:

```
import lxml.html as lh
doc=lh.parse(test.xml)

In [70]: persons = doc.xpath('.//person/@name')

In [71]: urls=doc.xpath('.//person[@name]/following-sibling::url/@name')

In [72]: mids=doc.xpath('.//person[@name]/preceding-sibling::mid/@name')

In [73]: [[p,m,u]for p,m,u in zip(persons, mids, urls)]
Out[73]: 
[['yyyyyyyyyy', 'yyyyyyyyyyyyy', 'yyyyyyyyy'],
 ['xxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxx']]
```